# How to change (remove then add) a background to a button in Android?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, background

I am trying to change the `background` of a button dynamically. The button already has a background gradient attributed to it in `main.xml`. I have tried:

```
featuredimage.setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.black_gradient));
```

But get the following error :

```
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at My.Taste.App.MyTasteActivity.changeCatagory(MyTasteActivity.java:188)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at My.Taste.App.MyTasteActivity.access$0(MyTasteActivity.java:160)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at My.Taste.App.MyTasteActivity$8.onClick(MyTasteActivity.java:155)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-03 23:16:12.279: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And yes the black_gradient file exists.

Additional code:

```
featuredimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.featuredimage);
featuredinfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.featuredinfo);
featuredinfo.setText(Html.fromHtml("<center><big><b>FEATURED " + catagory + "</b></big></center><br>" + getFeatured().getMediumString()));
```

Comment: This is the import part of the logcat: `java.lang.NullPointerException ... at My.Taste.App.MyTasteActivity.changeCatagory(MyTasteActivity.java:188)` **First,** is that code above line 188 from MyTasteActivity? **Second,** a NullPointerException is cause by calling `null.something()` so either `featuredimage` or `res` is `null`.

Comment: To answer the first part, the code is on line 188 and the error is only thrown when I attempt to access that part of the code which is blocked off inside of an 'if statement' and is the only line inside the statement so I am fairly certain it is the problem.

Comment: Ok, please post more of your code so we can see where you initialize `featuredimage` and `res`.

Comment: Secondly, I tested which part of the statement is throwing the error and it is definitely the .getDrawable(). Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: You were correct about the res returning null. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something wrong with your `res`. try this :

```
featuredimage.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_gradient));
```

You can also use [android.view.View.setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

> featuredimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_gradient);